# Lens spaces are rational homology sphere.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Is all lens spaces are manifold? if not then under what condition lens spaces become a manifold? what is dimension of these spaces. Moreover all these spaces are rational homology spheres in manifold case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z/pZ}$ acts freely on $S^3$, and resultant quotient spaces are called lens spaces. Since the group is finite and free, so the resultant space is manifold.[you can generalized that into higher dimesional odd spheres as well en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space#Definition ]

Observe that Lens spaces are orientable (as Jason DeVito mentioned) since the group action on $S^{2n+1}$ is orientable preserving. So an orientation on sphere descends to an orientation on $M$.
In order to prove that they are rational homology spheres, it is enough to prove that given any $u\in H_i(M,\mathbb Z), 0<i<n$ there exists some fixed integer $k$ s.t $ku=0$. Let $f:S^3\to M$ be the universal covering map. Let $deg(f)=k$ ( since it is a finite cover). Then $f_*(S^3)=k[M]$. Given any $u\in H_i$ there exists an unique $b\in H^{n-i}$ s.t. $[M]\cap b= u$ {Poincare Duality}. Then $ku= k[M]\cap b= f_*([S^3])\cap b= f_*( [S^3]\cap f^*(b)) =0$ (since $f^*(b)=0$). Thus $M$ is a rational homology sphere.

This same argument works for higher dimension as well.

Comment: Minor nitpick:  In order to prove $M$ is a rational homology sphere, you must also show that $H_n(M;\mathbb{Q})\neq 0$.  (This fails for $\mathbb{Z}_2/\mathbb{Z}$ actions on $S^{2n}$!).  It's true in this case-  in fact, any map of $S^{2n+1|$ with no fixed points must be orientation preserving by the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, so an orientation on $S^{2n+1}$ descends to an orientation on $M$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you very much for your comment. I should mention that...

Comment: @JasonDeVito how do you prove it using Lefschetz fixed point theorem? I can't see any immediate proof.

Comment: If a map $f:S^{2n+1}\rightarrow S^{2n+1}$ is an orientation reversing homeomorphism, then it acts by $+1$ on $H_0$ and as $-1$ on $H_{2n+1}$.  Thus, the Lefschetz number of $f$ is $ (-1)^0 (1) + (-1)^{2n+1}(-1) = 2\neq 0$, so any such $f$ has a fixed point.